# App Catalog at the Site Collection level is not working

Tags: web-part, spfx

I have set up the App Catalog at Site Collection level by following this link: [Manage the Site Collection App Catalog](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-Site-Collection-App-Catalog-928b9b61-a9de-4563-a7d1-6231aa9d4d19)

However, when I add an SPFx webpart into the App Catalog at Site Collection level, it is not deploying it.

[image]

I did this in a different tenant and it works fine there. Is there any setting that I am missing?

Comment: environment is On-premise or?

Comment: @Goshky It is SPO

Comment: Update yo template and Check environment  type..

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? @Sudhakar

Answer (score 0):

Site collection app catalog not showing deploy popup automatically. So first Upload the app, then from ribbon manually click Deploy

[image]